# laravel upload Can't write image data to path

Tags: php, laravel, base64

I'm trying to store `base64Image` with laravel but it returns this error:

```
Can't write image data to path (/home/u187504358/domains/example.com/public/images/Group-1590235658.jpg)
```

## Code

```
if ($request->photo) {
    $photo = $request->photo;
    $filename = 'Group' . '-' . time() . '.' . 'jpg';
    $location = public_path('images/'. $filename);
    Image::make(file_get_contents($photo))->resize(500, 500)->save($location);

    $oldFilename = $group->photo;
    if(!empty($group->photo)){
        Storage::delete($oldFilename);
    }
    $group->photo = $filename;
}
```

`filesystem.php`

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),
'disks' => [

  'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path('images/'),
  ],
]
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved

I've added this code to my `index.php` file in `public aka public_html` folder and it works now

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

> Note:
>   As you see in error it tries to connect with folder `public (domains/example.com/public/images)` but in server (shared host) there is `public_html` folder. So it made me think twice that laravel tries to connect to the wrong path and code above solved the issue.

-Hope it help others.